# ASP.NET Conversion of DataRow[] to DataTable

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, datatable, datarow

How to get a DataTable from DataRow[] collection ?

I tried  the following conversion , but it returns null.

```
    string ProcessQuery(ref DataRow[] rows)
            {
                DataTable _tb = new DataTable();

                foreach (DataRow _dr in rows)
                {
                    _tb.Rows.Add(_dr); 
                }
                _tb.AcceptChanges(); 
...
...
           }
```

Request your help.

Comment: what does return null? tb==null? tb.Rows==null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each dataRow has a Table property,
So if you have the datarows DataRow[] just pick any row and go:

```
rows[0].Table

string ProcessQuery(ref DataRow[] rows) 
        { 
            DataTable _tb = rows[0].Table; 
            // other stuff
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

should it not be _tb.importRow()?